# Control Structures and Functions inside lambda

Tags: python

Create a lambda function `greater`, which takes two arguments x and y and return x if x>y otherwise y. input value is (9,3)

```
greater= lambda a,b:a>b
if a>b:
    print(a)
else:
    return b
print(greater(a,b))
```

> File "/code/source.py3", line 11
>       return b
>          ^
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Even I am getting error in return statement.
I have to only get the output as value but I am getting value with True.

Comment: Control structures are not allowed in lambda but there is an [expression variant of `if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (conditional expression) which may be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` - `else` in `lambda`:

```
greater = lambda a, b: a if a > b else b
```

and call it as:

```
greater(9, 13)
```

**Problems** with your code:

- Your `lambda` function just compares two variables and returns a `True` / `False`.
- You used `return` outside a function which is not allowed. (Btw, there is no need of explicit `if` - `else` outside `lambda` when you can do within).

Answer (score 0):

You don't return from a lambda function.

```
greater = lambda a,b: a if a > b else b
print(greater(3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators (`a if a > b else c`) in lambdas but control structures require the `def` keyword

Also, there is no `return` in a lambda function

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ternary](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) if in your lambda:

```
greater = lambda x,y: x if x>y else y
greater(1,3)  # 3
greater(4,3)  # 4
```

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required. They are syntactically restricted to a single expression.

[Read more.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using ternary expression:

```
greater = lambda a, b: (a, b)[a<b]
```

`a<b` returns the boolean value `False` if `a` is greater than, or equal to, `b`, and `True` if `a` is smaller than `b`. We use the boolean value (basically representing `0` or `1`) as an index to the `tuple` `(a, b)` to return our desired result.